# OfficeJS Multiple Bindings in one GetDataAsync request

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I have an OfficeJS Manifest file to link to this `.html` file, and a button event that is tied to `executefunction`.  My problem comes with getting multiple different values from different tabs so that I can make an `AJAX` request to a web server.

```
(function () {

    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            registerBindings();
        });
    }

    function registerBindings() {
        Office.context.document.bindings.add("Sheet1!A1", "range", "binding_a");
        Office.context.document.bindings.add("Sheet2!A1", "range", "binding_b");
        Office.context.document.bindings.add("Sheet3!A1", "range", "binding_c");
        Office.context.document.bindings.add("Sheet4!A1:C3", "range", "results");
        return context.sync();
    }

})();

// function file execution must be global
function executefunction() {
    Office.select("bindings#binding_a", ...).getDataAsync(type,
        function (result) { // callback function
            Office.select("bindings#results").setDataAsync = $.AJAX(result.values)
        })
    event.completed();
}
```

Thus, how can you select multiple bindings and "package" them with the `result.values` from the `getDataAsync` callback?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your conflating two different API sets, the original [Shared API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/javascript-api-for-office) and the newer [Excel API](https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/requirement-sets/excel-api-requirement-sets). While these APIs coexist within `office.js`, they work a little differently.

Using the Excel API, you're code should look something like this:

```
function registerBindings() {
    return Excel.run(function (context) {
        // Set your bindings
        context.workbook.bindings.add("Sheet1!A1", "Range", "binding_a");
        context.workbook.bindings.add("Sheet2!A1", "Range", "binding_b");
        context.workbook.bindings.add("Sheet3!A1", "Range", "binding_c");
        context.workbook.bindings.add("Sheet4!A1:C3", "Range", "results");

        // Save the bindings to the document
        return context.sync();
    });
}

// function file execution must be global
function executefunction() {
    return Excel.run(function (context) {

        // Request your bindings
        let bindingA = context.workbook.bindings.getItem("binding_a").getRange().load();
        let bindingB = context.workbook.bindings.getItem("binding_b").getRange().load();
        let bindingC = context.workbook.bindings.getItem("binding_c").getRange().load();

        // Execute your binding request
        return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                console.log(bindingA.values);
                // Make your ajax call
                $.ajax({ /*...*/ })
                    .done(function (result) {

                        // Write the result to the workbook
                        context.workbook.bindings.getItem("results")
                            .getRange().values = result.values;

                        return context.sync();
                    });
            })
    });
}
```

Note that the calls to the Excel API are made within the `Excel.run(function (context) {...});` function. This is required in order to establish the proper context for the API.

Also note that before you can read the bindings to send to your REST method, you must first `load()` these ranges into your `context`.

Comment: Thank you very much, this is all new territory for me.  I'm guessing the `office.init` will still need to be wrapped in an anonymous function that calls `registerBindings` once the DOM is loaded?

Comment: There are plenty of good reasons for wrapping `Office.initialize` but it isn't required.  The only requirement is that you pass a function to the `initialize` property of the `Office` object.

Comment: Great, so the `manifest.xml`s `SourceLocation` will know to call `Office.initalize` when it visits my https site?

Comment: The `office.js` library will create an `Office` object when the page loads. This object has a property called `initialize` which takes a function. Once the lib completes wiring things up, it calls the `initialize` method to finalize everything. This happens on every page your add-in loads so this isn't just the `SourceLocation`, it's on every page your add-in loads.

Comment: So just to clarify, is this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands documentation not appropriate for excel-addins?  Because it specifies that the `event.completed()` is required for a button javascript function (`executefunction`) but you don't call it anywhere?

Comment: No, the docs are correct but remember that commands are calling into your [`FunctionFile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/develop/create-addin-commands#step-5-add-the-functionfile-element) not the page provided to `SourceLocation`.